# Как правильно называется title сайт, если искать через гугл и как его изменить? (см. скрин)

Tags: javascript, html, html5, google-chrome, google-search

[image: Title сайта]

На моем сайте не совсем правильно отображается этот title, как его правильно назвать я тоже не совсем понимаю

Comment: Ищите то, что отображает гугл в ваших html файлах в теге `<title>` - вот там и надо менять

Comment: В этом и проблема, что в мета тегах ничего и близко нет. В моем случае title сайта выглядит примерно так - "StackOverflow", а в гугле (и только в гугле, в обведенной области) указано "Stack overflow"

Comment: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/site-names?hl=ru

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за ссылку, надо было добавить - `<meta itemprop="name" content="Example"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете изменить заголовок веб-страницы с помощью JavaScript, установив новое значение свойства document.title. Например, вы можете использовать следующий код:

```
  <script>
      document.title = 'StackOverflow';
  </script>
```

Просто вставьте этот код в вашу веб-страницу, и измените "StackOverflow" на ваше значение.

Comment: И вас даже не смутило, что текст, обведённый на скриншоте, не совпадает ни с одним title на сайте?

Comment: у меня этот скрин не загружаеться, описал простой пример как можно внести изменения в заголовок с помощью JS